# Office 2010 on Mac OS 10.8: Drawing a Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a simple data set and I want to make a graph for it.

```
Years   Upper Band  Lower Band
2010    0.73        0.63
2020    1.04        0.83
2030    1.36        1.06
2040    1.74        1.31
2050    2.19        1.54
2060    2.83        1.77
2070    3.43        1.96
2080    3.97        2.12
2090    4.42        2.24
2100    4.82        2.31
```

I want to plot these 2 series against years and shade the region in the middle. I tried doing an area graph and using white color for the color of the lower region and even did no-line. That gives me a desired shaded region but leaves a pesky shaded line at the boundaries of the region which I filled with white color, which looks really ugly. This is for a presentation and I cannot have such lines there.

Comment: The pesky shaded line is a shadow that Excel for Mac always applied (Microsoft got smart and left shadows off of charts in Excel for Windows). After creating the chart, before doing anything else, you can apply one of the chart styles that does not have these shadows, then do the rest of your formatting. Otherwise, you can remove the shadows one series at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! It's a shame that Excel doesn't have such graphing capabilities "out of the box". I took the following steps:

- Add a column to your data with the width of the band (UpperBand - LowerBand).
- Use the "Stacked area" graph type and graph only the Lower Band and the Band width.
- Set the filling of the Lower Band to transparent and draw no lines around that data.

The resulting graph should look something like this.

[image: Band chart in Excel]